# Site is getting hanged when select value from dropdown in IE-11 using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I have an issue. when user is selecting any value from drop down list the site is not functioning at all in `IE-11`. Its working in all other browser. Please check my code below.

```
<select class="form-control" id="answer_{{$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}_category" name="answer_{{$index}}_category" ng-model="answer.category" ng-options="cat.name for cat in listOfCategory track by cat.value" ng-change="removeBorder($index,answer.category.value,$parent.$index)" ng-init="renderWithMode($index,answer.category.value,$parent.$index,isEditMode)">
 <option value="">Select Category</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="answer_{{$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}_subcategory" name="answer_{{$index}}_subcategory" ng-model="answer.subcategory" ng-options="sub.name for sub in listOfSubCategory[$parent.$index][$index] track by sub.value">
<option value="">Select Subcategory</option>
</select>
```

Controller side code is given below.

```
$http({
        method:'GET',
        url:"php/customerInfo.php?action=cat",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        console.log('res',response.data);
        angular.forEach(response.data,function(obj){
            var data={'name':obj.cat_name,'value':obj.cat_id};
            $scope.listOfCategory.push(data);
        })
    },function errorCallback(response) {
    })

$scope.removeBorder=function(index,catvalue,parent,com){

     // answer_{{$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}_comment
     // console.log('ind',index,catvalue,parent,document.getElementById('answer_'+index+'_'+parent+'_comment').value);
     //$scope['listOfSubCatagory'+parent][index]=[];
    //$scope.listOfSubCatagory[index][parent]=[[]];
    //$scope.listOfSubCatagory[index] = []
   // $scope.listOfSubCatagory[index][parent] = []
   var subcategories=[];
     var catdata=$.param({'action':'subcat','cat_id':catvalue});
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:"php/customerInfo.php",
            data:catdata,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            angular.forEach(response.data,function(obj){
                var data={'name':obj.subcat_name,'value':obj.subcat_id};
                if(!$scope.listOfSubCategory[parent]){
                      $scope.listOfSubCategory[parent] = [];  
                }
                //console.log('data',data);
                subcategories.push(data);
            })
            $scope.listOfSubCategory[parent][index]=subcategories;
        },function errorCallback(response) {
        }) 
  }
```

Here two drop down list are present inside a table.When user selects category the respective sub-category should set in the second drop down list.Its working fine in all other browser but in `IE-11` while selecting subcategory drop down list the site is getting hanged.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: @AnoopLL : No error in console. Its working fine all other browser.